# How to save a copy of a multiplayer world in the new 0.7+ menus?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you save a joined game after the 0.7.1 update? The menus have all changed since 0.6.x and I can't find the option to save a copy of a joined world anymore. (My friend has got a diamond house on survival and I want to save it but it doesn't let me!)

Comment: 0.7.1 Alpha? As far as I know, the game is fully released. I smell something fishy here...

Comment: Also, surely if you've joined *their* game then you can't save, it's theirs to save (if it doesn't save automatically).

Comment: Oliviaa did not give any feedback what game she means. So why did you edit it without knowing anything? That is just wrong. Edits based on assumptions are not right.

Comment: @none It's in the title and 0.7.1 is the current version of PE, so it's not wrong.

Comment: @JohnW You can save a copy of multiplayer worlds you're just visiting, in PE. Version 0.7.0 changed all the menus though, so lots of people are trying to figure out where old options have moved to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The menu option for this is missing from the new menus.

This might be a deliberate removal of the world-saving feature, or it might just be an oversight in the design of the new menus. Either way, you can't with version 0.7.0 or 0.7.1.

Source: Testing with two copies of Minecraft PE on 0.7.0 then 0.7.1.

Answer (score -1):

They took it out because too many people were having a problem when they saved the game. Talk to Mojang about it!

Comment: It does sound plausible, but it would be nice to have a source to that claim. One- or two sentence answers are generally not welcome.